# подключение OpenGL к проекту на Perl

Tags: opengl, perl

Собственно, на mac os уже есть OpenGL и он нормально работает с проектами на С++. Захотел прикрутить его к проекту на Perl. Столкнулся с проблемой:

```
Can't locate OpenGL.pm in @INC (you may need to install the OpenGL module) (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.18 /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.18 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.18 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18 .) at /Users/stolz/code/perl/cg/triangle.pl line 3.
```

`BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/stolz/code/perl/cg/triangle.pl line 3.`

Третья строка - это `Use OpenGL;`

Как мне установить этот OpenGL модуль?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В некторых дистрибутивах linux многие модули perl устанавливаются штатным средством установки пакетов. Например для gentoo `emerge dev-perl/OpenGL`.

Если ваша система не поддерживает установку модулей perl, то вам надо использовать идущее в комплекте с perl средство установки:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

При первом выполнении этой команды вам потребуется ответить на некоторые вопросы. После этого оно возможно предложит установить еще некоторые пакеты для его корректной работы. После того как все это будет выполнено вы сможете дать в нем команду `install OpenGL`.

Для корректной работы установщика CPAN вам возможно потребуется наличие подходящего ему компилятора языка C (обычно gcc). И некоторых других средств сборки приложений.

Дополнительную информацию по модулям perl и их установку можно найти на [cpan.org](http://cpan.org)