# ошибка glpOpenWindow на Perl OpenGL

Tags: opengl, perl

есть код:

```
use OpenGL
sub glInit {
  glpOpenWindow();
  glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
  glFrustum(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 20.0);
}
glInit();
print "Press return to exit\n";
while ( <> ) {
  exit;
}
```

На строчке `glpOpenWindow();` выдает ошибку:

```
Goto undefined subroutine &AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD at /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/OpenGL.pm line 6110.
```

Как это можно вылечить?

Comment: Судя по текущему вопросу, Вы нашли решение для этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511330/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-opengl-%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-perl напишите его там.

Comment: Покажите часть кода около строки 6110 в данном файле `/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/OpenGL.pm`

Comment: @edem `$AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD = $AUTOLOAD;`

`goto &AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Долго копаясь серча интернеты так и ничего не нашел. В самом `OpenGL.pm` нашел строчку на которой падает все:

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
# This AUTOLOAD is used to 'autoload' constants from the constant()
# XS function.  If a constant is not found then control is passed
# to the AUTOLOAD in AutoLoader.

# NOTE: THIS AUTOLOAD FUNCTION IS FLAWED (but is the best we can do for now).
# Avoid old-style ``&CONST'' usage. Either remove the ``&'' or add ``()''.
if (@_ > 0) {

    # Is it an old OpenGL-0.4 function? If so, remap it to newer variant
local($constname);
($constname = $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/.*:://;
if (grep ($_ eq $constname, @rename_old)) {
    eval "sub $AUTOLOAD { $AUTOLOAD" . "_s(\@_) }";
    goto &$AUTOLOAD;
}

    $AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD = $AUTOLOAD;
    goto &AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD; #LINE 6110
}
```

По `THIS AUTOLOAD FUNCTION IS FLAWED` можно догадаться, что проблема в модуле. Так что мое решение было таковым:

Я подключил `Glut` и использовал его для создания окна. Все собралось отлично, `OpenGL` рисует примитивы.