# CPAN удаление пакета

Tags: perl

Установил через CPAN пакет, и он встал криво, можно ли его удалить, либо переустановить?

Comment: попробуйте просто install он должен заменить пакет. Еще рекомендуют, если сохранился каталог из которого ставился модуль (он остается в /root/.cpan/ или где то у текущего пользователя) выполнить в нем `make uninstall`

Comment: Напишите ответ для своего вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/511330/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-opengl-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

более-менее универсальный способ - с помощью клиента cpanm:

```
$ cpanm -U Foo # удалить пакет Foo
$ cpanm -SU Foo # удалить пакет Foo, запуск из-под суперпользователя
```

Внимание, важно что бы *install_base* совпадал с тем, что вы использовали при установки CPAN модуля , как правило это так, но если что - указать install_base, в котором cpanm будет искать модуль, можно с помощью ключа -l:

```
$ cpanm -l ~/ -U Foo # удалить пакет Foo, установленный в install_base = домашнему каталогу
```

Подробнее обо всем этом тут - https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm#uninstall--U